# PHP strstr - The reverse method

Tags: php, string, echo, trim, strstr

I'm looking to get the same exact results as php strstr command (while it set to true) but in reverse order.

I know that I can simply reverse the string and use strstr and then reverse it again

but I was wonder if there is any internal php command for the task.

```
<?php

$myString = 'We don\'t need no education';

echo strstr($myString, ' ', true);

/*
 * output :
 * We
 *
 * I'm expecting to get :
 * education
 *
 */

exit;

?>
```

Very Simple !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the function [strrchr](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php)

```
$myString = 'We don\'t need no education';

echo strrchr($myString, ' ');
// output : ' education'

echo substr(strrchr($myString, ' '), 1);
// output : 'education'
```

Comment: This answer is partly misleading. `strrchr` is **not** a reverse `strstr`. As the [official documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) states, `strrchr` searches for the last occurence of a *character* in the string, not for any string. If the needle passed to `strrchr` contains more than one character, only the first one is used. Luckily because OP searches for one character only, this worked here.

Comment: @Neonit removed the misleading part

Answer (score 2):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php#103577 (in the comments)

```
function rstrstr($haystack,$needle)
{
    return substr($haystack, 0, strpos($haystack, $needle));
}
```

Author: Dennis T Kaplan

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
   $myString = 'This is a string';
   $words = explode(' ', $myString);
   $lastWord = array_pop($words);
```

Wrap it in a function

```
function lastWord($string) {
   return array_pop(explode(' ', $string));
}
```

Is this helping you further.

Comment: array_pop expects the parameter to be a reference to an array it can manipulate... so in some versions of php it won't accept the expression and you'll have to declare a variable.

Answer (score 0):

using str :

```
$basename = strrev(substr(strchr(strrev($postfile_name),'.'),1)); 
//test.php will return test

$ext = strrchr( $postfile_name, '.' ); 
//test.php will return .php
```